# vbscript to change drive letter

Tags: vbscript

Want to change drive letter of volumes. once the script is run it should show the partitions in pop up box and ask for new drive letters.

Used below code but it is just changing the d to q

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colVolumes = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Volume Where Name = 'D:\\'")

For Each objVolume in colVolumes
objVolume.DriveLetter = "Q:"
objVolume.Put_
Next
```

Comment: Please provide more detail. It's not clear to me what you actually want to achieve. Do you want to assign drive letters to unmounted volumes?

Comment: i want to have three drive letters which "c" "d" "v" and dvd drive "e". so for every system i have to change manually in manage option. So i want to achieve this in script when i run the script a box should open and show the partitions and ask for new drive letter. For example ... Partition 1 150gb = enter new letter.... partition 2 1tb = enter new letter.

Comment: I still don't understand. If you want to interactively change drive letters, you could simply do this with `diskmgmt.msc`.

Comment: Yes, but i,m going to run a single script which will change IP address, Computer name, Check for secondary monitor with HDCP, clear temp files along with this script i want to add this drive letter changing script.

Comment: Unless you intend to fully automate changing the drive letters, you're better off using something like `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "diskmgmt.msc", 1, True`.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite 5 years late to the party. Here is a handy script that I wrote using the script above that originally came from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ccae4d09-1bee-4f10-8c8c-176a53a65238

I plug USB drives in and out frequently, and I have a couple of devices that I like to have "permanently" assigned to specific drive letters. Save this code in a text file and rename it to: ChangeDriveLetter.vbs

Put the file somewhere on your computer, then create a shortcut to it on the desktop or anywhere you want. Then right-click on the shortcut and specify the keyboard shortcut you would like to use to open it any time you want to change a drive letter or two.

This works on Windows 10

```
    ' Elevate the script to run As Administrator 

If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevate", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If

' Ask the user which drive to change, and what to change it to.
Sub subAskUser()

    strSourceDrive = InputBox("What Drive to Reassign","Enter the drive letter to reassign:","D")

    If ((strSourceDrive = vbCancel) Or (strSourceDrive = "") Or IsEmpty(strSourceDrive)) Then

        WScript.Quit

    End If

    strTargetDrive = InputBox("What Letter to Assign","Enter the new drive letter:","Q")

    If ((strTargetDrive = vbCancel) Or (strTargetDrive = "") Or IsEmpty(strTargetDrive)) Then

        WScript.Quit

    End If

    'If The letters are present and the user did not cancel, then call the Subroutine to change the letters
    subChangeLetter strSourceDrive, strTargetDrive

End Sub

subAskUser()

Sub subChangeLetter(strSourceDrive, strTargetDrive)

    'Check that the C: drive is not the letter that the user is trying to change from or to.
    If ((strSourceDrive <> "C") And (strSourceDrive <> "c") And (strTargetDrive <> "C") And (strTargetDrive <> "c")) Then

            'Uncomment the next lines to see the values entered from the InputBox
            'MsgBox strSourceDrive
            'MsgBox strTargetDrive

            strComputer = "."
            Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
            & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

            Set colVolumes = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
            ("Select * from Win32_Volume Where Name = '"& UCase(strSourceDrive) & ":\\'")

            For Each objVolume in colVolumes
            objVolume.DriveLetter = UCase( strTargetDrive) & ":"
            objVolume.Put_
            Next

    Else

        MsgBox "Ah, ah, ah! You can't change the C: drive, dude!",16

    End If

End Sub

strGoAgain = MsgBox("Change another drive letter?",4)

If strGoAgain = vbYes Then

    subAskUser()

End If

WScript.Quit
```